# EF 6 Code First mapping existing database with discriminator and TPT

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a problem that I have struggled with for a while now.

Given the following existing tables in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModuleData] (
  ItemID INT NOT NULL,
  DataType INT NOT NULL,
  DataID  INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Costs] ( -- DataType = 2
  CostID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  Amount MONEY NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actions] ( -- DataType = 4
  ActionID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  Note NVARCHAR (1000) NULL,
);
```

I would like to map them against the following classes:

```
public class ModuleData
{
    public int ItemID {get; set;}
    public int DataID { get; set; }
    public int DataType { get; set; }
}

public class Cost:ModuleData
{
    public Cost()
    {
        //DataType = 2;
    }
    public int CostID {get; set;}
    public Double Amount {get; set;}
}

public class Action: ModuleData
{
    public Action()
    {
        //DataType = 4;
    }
    public int ActionID { get; set; }
    public String Note {get; set;}
}
```

Using `DataType` as a discriminator and `DataID` as the key.

I get the impression that it should be possible with the fluent API but I just can't get it to  work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `EntityTypeConfiguration<ModuleData>`, put

```
Map<Cost>(m => m.Requires("DataType").HasValue(2));
Map<Action>(m => m.Requires("DataType").HasValue(4));
```

Or in your `OnModelCreating` write

```
modelbuilder.Entity<ModuleData>()
    .Map<Cost>(m => m.Requires("DataType").HasValue(2))
    .Map<Action>(m => m.Requires("DataType").HasValue(4));
```

Hope this helps!